# How to output verbatim strings in C++

Tags: c++

Suppose I need to output some program code from my C++ code. So I need to print things like:

```
cout << "foo(\"hello\", \"world\", 5)" << endl;
```

Is there a way so that I do not need to escape each " ?

Comment: It depends on the context of application you want to use the output in. There are many options:

1) You can use single-quoted (') character.

2) If you are reading the input string from a file, then there is no need to escape " since the string automatically takes care of " itself.

Comment: While single quote is an option, but I would loose the flexibility to use double quotes. Actually, I'm looking for some solution (perhaps template metaprogramming) to translate a string literal to another string literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C++03, you can use a Macro to do what you want:

```
#define PRINT_STRING(s) cout << (#s) << endl;

int main() {
    cout << "foo(\"hello\", \"world\", 5)" << endl;
    PRINT_STRING(foo("hello", "world", 5))
    return 0;
}
```

Returns

```
output:
foo("hello", "world", 5)
foo("hello", "world", 5)
```

You can see it here: http://ideone.com/G6TvU3

Answer (score 14):

With C++11 you can do

`R"delimeter(foo("hello", "world",5))delimeter"`

Where `R"delimeter(` defines the start of a raw string,  `delimeter` is a label up to 16 characters, and `)delimeter"` ends the raw string.

Comment: Yes, I wish I could use C++11, but our compiler is not yet ready to support that. I'm actually looking for some template metaprogramming solution to this question.

Comment: C++03 does not support raw string literals.  Only `"` and `L"` for regular character and wide character null terminated strings.  If you're looking to avoid escaping `"`s then there is literally no solution to your problem aside from using some sort of preprocessor magic maybe.

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports C++11 the multiline quote construct is `R"LABEL(` Where LABEL is a valid label.  To end the quote use `)LABEL"`